# How to build a game for linux in unity

Tags: unity, build-process

I made a game and uploaded it to a game site. I exported the build as windows mac OS and Linux. My thinking was that it supported all of those platforms but i guess not. Someone commented saying that the game didn't support linux. I have no idea why since it said it built for mac and windows and linux. Do i have to change settings? If so were? if its target platform i cant because the only option is windows.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to release a game for a platform you never tested it on yourself. Even when your game engine claims to be able to export to some platform, there can often be platform-specific problems which require some manual troubleshooting and implementations of workarounds to solve.

Comment: It mentioned Linux in the export option so it only made sense... Yes I probably should have done a bit more research but its not on gamedev stack exchange so I may as well increase the knowledge shared on the platform. I will do more research to see if I can however and maybe answer my own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't installed build support for Linux binaries in Unity. The way to do this in Unity can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GettingStartedAddingEditorComponents.html):

1. Open the Hub.
2. Select Installs.
3. Find the Editor you want to add the components to.
4. Click the three dots to the right of the version label, then select Add Modules. (NOTE: If you didn’t install the Editor via the Hub, you will not see this option. To enable this option, install the Editor via the Hub.)
5. In the Add Modules dialog, locate the module to add and tick its checkbox.
6. When you have selected all the modules to add, select Done.

Note that while Unity can export binaries to other platforms, you probably still want to test the output binary on a system with the target platform, perhaps in a VM for an example.